# MySQL/PostgreSQL record search: any alternative to LIKE?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm implementing a search system in my system and i'm curious about the usage of LIKE. Many websites and books "crucify" the usage of LIKE. But, what's the proper alternative? I really don't want to install a third-party system like Elasticsearch or similar.

Comment: Depends on what you're searching.  To score text column(s) against a querystring, consider [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Cite your sources, please.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut: I dunno his sources, but I feel safe to wager it's ranting about how `foo like '%bar%'` will yield — surprise! — a seq scan. Which then gets merge joined with tags and what not. That can be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For search, the usual approach is the (very powerful) full text search functionality:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html

Depending on your specific needs, there also are colorful tools such as n-grams and a case-insensitive text type in contrib:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html